# ReduceByKey after return from function which has return type Either

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd, variadic-functions

I need to aggregate 3 different `RDDs`(in 3 different iterations) on which I am using `map` to call a function `createKeyValuePair` which has return type `Either[((Long, Int, Int),A), ((Int, Int, Int, Int),A)]`,

```
sparkSession.sqlContext.read.parquet(inputPathForCut: _*).rdd
      .map(row => createKeyValuePair(row, data, keyElements))
      .reduceByKey((r1,r2) => Utils.aggregateRecords(r1,r2))
      .toDF()
      .coalesce(1)
      .write.format("parquet").option("compression", "gzip")
      .save(OUTPUT_PATH)
```

But, then `reduceByKey` is not available, it says `cannot resolve reduceByKey`.

```
def createKeyValuePair(row: Row, data: String, elementsInKey: Int) : Either[((Long, Int, Int), A),
                                                                    ((Int, Int, Int, Int, Int), A)] = {
    var keySet = Array[Long]()
    for (i <- 0 to elementsInKey) {
        keySet = keySet :+ row(i).asInstanceOf[Long]
    }
    val record = row(elementsInKey).asInstanceOf[A]
    dataCut match {
        case "string1" => return ... //(first key)
        case "string2" => return ... //(second key)
    }
    null
}
```

## Question 1. How can I use `reduceByKey` on RDD returned by function call which has return type `Either`?

If I change function `createKeyValuePair` to following,

```
def createKeyValuePair(row: Row, data: String, elementsInKey: Int) : ((Long*, Int*), A) = {
    var keySet = Array[Long]()
    for (i <- 0 to elementsInKey) {
        keySet = keySet :+ row(i).asInstanceOf[Long]
    }
    val record = row(elementsInKey).asInstanceOf[A]

    ((keySet: _*),record)
}
```

then `reduceByKey` works, but it thinks return type is just `((Long,Int),A)`, and the function shows error as well, that return type expected is `(Long,Int)`, but actual is `Seq[A]`.

## Question 2. Is it not possible to have return type as varargs in scala?

### Note: The return type and data on which `reduceByKey` will be applied have same schema. I am not trying to apply `reduceByKey` on data with different schemas. I will first read file 1 and file 2 and aggregate that, which will have key as `(Long,Int,Int)`, then in 2nd iteration will read second file which will have key as `(Int, Int, Int, Int)` and aggregate that.

Answer (score 1):

`reduceByKey` is only available for RDDs of (key, value) pairs, which you don't actually have (because they're wrapped in the `Either`).

One option is to change from `RDD[((Long, Int, Int),A), ((Int, Int, Int, Int),A)]` to `RDD[(Either[(Long, Int, Int), (Int, Int, Int, Int)], A)]`.

However, I'm not convinced that you should have a single `createKeyValuePair` function. The only code you actually share between the two cases is building the array of keys. Imagine instead something like

```
def getKeyElements(row: Row, recordIndex: Int): List[Long] = {
  (0 until recordIndex).map(row.getLong).toList
}

def createKeyValuePairFirstCase(row: Row): ((Long, Int, Int), A) = {
  val first :: second :: third :: _ = getKeyElements(row, 3)
  ((first, second, third), row.get(3).asInstanceOf[A])
}
```

and similarly in the second case. I believe (though I'm not sure and didn't check) that you get an implicit conversion from `Long` to `Int` in the keys.

A few random notes:

- We need `getKeyElements` to return a `List` to use pull out `first`, `second` and `third` like that. You could also just return a `Seq` and build the tuple using indices.
- Note the existence of `getLong`. There's also `getInt` and `getString` and so on.
- It does feel like there ought to be a way to parameterize the type of the key and write a single function, but I don't know what it is.
- Have you thought about using the new Dataset API? You might be able to make this easier to read and more robust.

Comment: Hey, very nice explanation. Thanks. `I'm not convinced that you should have a single createKeyValuePair`. The only reason for having one function was I was tying to use a `for` loop to do the same aggregation for 3 different files. Two had `Long, Int,int`, one had `(Int,Int,Int,Int,Int)`. I ended up writing 3 different pieces to read and aggregate for all 3.